# OpenTK OpenGL GLSL 3.30 Not Supported

Tags: c#, glsl, opentk, mesa

I'm trying to follow this tutorial (
http://neokabuto.blogspot.com/2013/03/opentk-tutorial-2-drawing-triangle.html ) on a lubuntu 14.04.1 laptop workstation using monodevelop.  When executing the program, I get

`GLSL 3.30 is not supported.  Supported versions are 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, and 1.00 E`

Through much research and asking on the ubuntu forums, I eventually got to a point where my laptop does indeed (appear to) contain GLSL 3.30, as seen by this:

`glxinfo | grep version
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.6.0-devel (git-345e8cc 2015-02-08 trusty-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.6.0-devel (git-345e8cc 2015-02-08 trusty-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 10.6.0-devel (git-345e8cc 2015-02-08 trusty-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00`

So I'm rather at a loss.  Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue (ubuntu 14.10) I fixed it by going into the shader files and changing the line that says

## version 330

to

## version 130